# clearListeners not working with 'domready' and 'rightclick'

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

[The jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZW79H/7/) is a revision of one contributed to by others. The user can click on the map to create one or more markers and submit a Title for each. User can then rightclick on any existing marker to delete that marker. I want the user to only be able to delete one marker, though, so I want to ignore any rightclicks after the first one. The code below shows my attempt to do so, as well as some commented out alternative attempts. The problem is that after the first marker is deleted, subsequent rightclicks are acknowledged. What am I doing wrong?

```
var domListener;

    domListener = google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {
    ...
    });

    // Right click event (to present delete marker button)
    delListener = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function () {
        infowindow.setContent(deleteButton);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker, 'rightclick');
        // google.maps.event.clearListeners(this, 'mouseup');
        // google.maps.event.removeListener(domListener);
    });
```

Comment: You have to collect all your `domListener`s for your markers and call `removeListener()` for remaining markers.

Comment: You say to collect all `domListeners`. I think I tried that by naming the only listener for 'domready' and then including the commented out line `google.maps.event.removeListener(domListener);`, but when I did that, the first delete did not even work -- submit, that is. Do you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `delListener`s. They are handles to markers `rightclick` events.

Comment: If you only want one event (the first), perhaps you should use [addListenerOnce](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapsEventListener)...

Comment: That fixed it. I added the following code `for (i = 0; i < delListeners.length; i++) { delListener = delListeners[i]; google.maps.event.removeListener(delListener);}` and a "collector" and I'm good.

Comment: @geocodezip I don't know which marker will be deleted first, so I doubt that addListenerOnce() would work if I am needing to "collect" the Listeners. I was surprised that such collection is required.